# How to insert new cell at first element in UICollectionView in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to make horizontal collection and add new cell at the first position.

I make custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout and override
LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect like this (to see reverse order of items):

```
    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        var attributes = new UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[cellCount];

        NSIndexPath indexPath;

        // Setting first position
        int shift = 25, reverseXCenter;
        for (int i = 0; i < cellCount; i++)
        {
            indexPath = NSIndexPath.FromItemSection(i, 0);

            attributes[i] = LayoutAttributesForItem(indexPath);

            // We have to make opposite order
            reverseXCenter = (cellCount -1 - i) * 50;
            attributes[i].Center = new CGPoint(reverseXCenter + shift, attributes[i].Center.Y);
        }

        return attributes;
    }
```

I think is bad solution, because when I have more than 5 cells, the displayed collection is filled and I can't scroll.
I had debugger in GetOrCreateCellFor in CollectionViewSource
and indexPath.Item's had value for example (10,9,8,7,6...), where 10 is the last I added.

Maybe is another way to do this, or just I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I am gonna help you out with a flow .

Suppose you are in a ViewController called "A" which will present a controller ViewController called "B"

Inside A use this function to push B

---

```
Public void PushNewHorizontalCollectionController(){
using (var vc =
                   new B(this.PageViewControllerLayout(), indexPath))
            {

                this.controller.PushViewController(pageViewController, true);
            }
}

public UICollectionViewFlowLayout PageViewControllerLayout()
        {


            var flowLayout = new UICollectionViewFlowLayout();
                var itemSize = this.controller.NavigationBarHidden ? new CGSize(Constants.ScreenWidth, Constants.ScreenHeight + 20) : new CGSize(Constants.ScreenWidth, Constants.ScreenHeight - Constants.NavigationHeaderAndStatusbarHeight);
                flowLayout.ItemSize = itemSize;
                flowLayout.MinimumLineSpacing = 0;
                flowLayout.MinimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
                flowLayout.ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal;
                return flowLayout;


        }
```

Here itemSize is CGSize which u can assign what size you can ignore my constants which are self explainable .

Inside B your constructor should look like this .

---

```
public HorizontalViewController(UICollectionViewLayout layout, NSIndexPath indexpath) : base(layout)
        {

Do your initialisation like registering UICollectionViewCell class nibs for use with this Controller 
        }
```

Handling real requirement from comment .

You wanna add something always as 1st element in collectionView ,Go to this method which should look like below

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    Console.WriteLine("getcellHori");

    var isQuoteType = Photo.PhotoCollection[(int)indexPath.Item].Type;
    if (isQuoteType == 3 || isQuoteType == 4)
    {
        var item = Photo.PhotoCollection[(int)indexPath.Item];

        var cell = (HorizontalviewForQuoteType)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("HorizontalviewForQuoteType", indexPath);
        cell.PopulateCell(item.Caption,item.TextLabel,item.Likes,item.TimeLabel,item.Id);




        HorizontalviewForQuoteType.pullAction = (offset) =>
        {
            this.pullOffset = offset;
            this.NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
        };
        cell.SetNeedsLayout();
        return cell;
    }
```

Here you this line

var item = Photo.PhotoCollection[(int)indexPath.Item];

this is the data source , so whenever you adding something at index first and everything will be solved .

Comment: I don't know how it will help with scrolling?
I made UICollectionViewFlowLayout with  ScrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal, but it works only when I don't change UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes.
I thought that I need to tell to UICollectionView something about scrolling

Comment: what do u mean by scrolling , when your class itself is UiCollectionViewController ,scrolling is enable by default ,If no of cell is more than screen you can scroll

Comment: I want to change display order. When I adding something it should show at first element, but default is last. I just can't figure out how to do it.
I changed layout attributes, but after that scroll is frozen.

Comment: ok I know now I have to override this two functions to do int properly: ,UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect), UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes LayoutAttributesForItem(NSIndexPath indexPath)

Comment: custom layout preparation has nothing to do with what you want , em are for how you arrange the cells , 2 in a row or 3 something like that .
mostly Ui customisation of Uicollectionviewcell.